# System.IO.File.OpenRead is working but System.IO.FileStream is not working?

Tags: c#, .net

In my application i am reading .PDF file useing System.IO.FileStream (filePath). This is working fine when folder have local user right. When i remove Local user right from folder that time this gives access denied error.
I am use this code...

```
System.IO.FileStream objFStream = new System.IO.FileStream(strPath, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
        byte[] bytRead = new byte[(int)objFStream.Length];
        objFStream.Read(bytRead, 0, (int)objFStream.Length);
        objFStream.Close();
        objFStream.Dispose();
```

Once i replace System.IO.FileStream to System.IO.File.OpenRead(strPath) it will work.
Replace code is...

```
System.IO.FileStream objFStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(strPath);
            byte[] bytRead = new byte[(int)objFStream.Length];
            objFStream.Read(bytRead, 0, (int)objFStream.Length);
            objFStream.Close();
            objFStream.Dispose();
```

I want to know what is the different between this?
If any one know please help.

Comment: Note that you probably want to use a `using` block to make sure the file gets closed if an exception is thrown anywhere.

Comment: What is the exact exception you get? Post exception name, message, stacktrace

Answer (score 6):

[`File.OpenRead`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,7a7d1c864bec521e) method uses `FileAccess.Read` while opening the file.It's the difference:

```
return new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
```

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47ek66wy(v=vs.100).aspx) says about the constructor you are using:

> For constructors without a `FileAccess` parameter, if the mode parameter is set to Append, Write is the default access. Otherwise, **the access is set to `ReadWrite`.**

So I guess you don't have permission to write the file. That's why it throws exception.You can verify this by trying opening the stream with `ReadWrite` access:

```
new FileStream(strPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  ... new System.IO.FileStream(strPath, System.IO.FileMode.Open)
```

When you only say "I want to open the file" then .NET doesn't know if you are going to read or write the file.  So it guesses at both to be on the safe side, FileAccess.ReadWrite.  However, file system directories very commonly only allow a user to read files and forbid writing.  Standard examples on any machine are the c:\windows and c:\program files directories and their sub-directories.  So the exception is nothing unexpected.

You have to be explicit about your intention with the file.  Like File.OpenRead() is implicitly by just its name.  You must add the FileAccess.Read argument.

---

Anecdotal: the File class was added to the framework very late.  Inspired by Microsoft conducting usability studies on the framework.  They asked experienced programmers whom otherwise never had seen .NET to use FileStream to write a sample program.  Nobody got it right.